# React Typescript fetch from Spring Data REST API "Property '_embedded' does not exist" issue

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, rest, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a React application with Typescript that fetches data from a Spring Data REST API (JPA repositories) when I send a request like
"GET http://localhost:8080/notifications/1", from a specific id, my JSON response has no typescript issues because it looks like this:

```
{
  "title" : "titulo",
  "content" : "conteúdo",
  "notificationPriority" : "medium",
  "seen" : true,
  "notificationType" : "Student",
  "createdAt" : null,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/notifications/1"
    },
    "notification" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/notifications/1"
    },
    "phase" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/notifications/1/phase"
    },
    "modality" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/notifications/1/modality"
    }
  }
```

So in a react component I can access with just "data.title" because the useEffect to fetch is totally fine, however when I'm doing a request like "GET http://localhost:8080/notifications" the JSON response looks like:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "notifications" : [ {
      "title" : "titulo",
      "content" : "conteúdo",
      "notificationPriority" : "medium",
      "seen" : true,
      "notificationType" : "Student",
      "createdAt" : null,
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/notifications/1"
        },
        "notification" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/notifications/1"
        },
        "phase" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/notifications/1/phase"
        },
        "modality" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/notifications/1/modality"
        }
      }
    }]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/notifications"
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/notifications"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

It should just access "data._embedded.notifications.title" and it should be rendered in the react component, but the typescript signs an error before fetching, so stills an empty object {} of any type, for a fraction of a second the component correctly renders until the typescript covers in the error screen showing:

"Property '_embedded' does not exist on type '{}'."

In component I set data as any to avoid this situation, how can I make typescript understand that there'll be _embedded when the data is fetched?

In the component, I already wait for the loading to render.

```
import React from 'react';
import Footer from '../templates/Footer';
import TopBar from '../NavLogged';
import NotificationList from '../Lists/NotificationList';
import useGetApi from '../utils/hooks/useGetApi';

export default function NotificationsPage() {
  const [notificationData, isLoading] = useGetApi({
    initialUrl: "http://localhost:8080/notifications"});
  return (
    <>
      <TopBar />
      {isLoading ? null : 
        <NotificationList
            data={notificationData._embedded.notifications}
            listTitle='Minhas Notificações'
          />
      }
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you're not typing `notifications` as an object with **structure**. To fix this, you'll want to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). In this case, you'll have to type the returned data structure:

```
type Notifications = {
  "_embedded": {
    notifications: Array<{
      title: string;
      content: string;
      notificationPriority: string;
      seen: boolean;
      notificationType: string;
      createdAt: null;
      "_links": {
        self: {
           href: string;
        };
        notification: {
           href: string;
        };
        phase: {
           href: string;
        };
        modality: {
           href: string;
        };
      };
    }>;
  };
  "_links": {
    self: {
      href: string;
    };
    profile: {
      href: string;
    };
  };
  page: {
    size: number;
    totalElements: number;
    totalPages: number;
    number: number;
  };
};
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sAlgM0QYwIZLgOwM5QC8UA3gFBRQBEA%20hALYBGEAJi61QFykWVQ4IU6LIlx5uAQQBOUjCAA85PnyTAANhG55gUxDgDmAbl7K0uYBBzAtOvUZN8BSVJmw4ACrri7QN3QeNlSjwIS25GODgNDBxAoKchV1EcABVwTShtf3sgqDQpCCxWCWt%20AFc1NTjlWjU9AGs8Lh5c4Ig1ZG4lVr4ACwLOzNsAh2UAX2r4wRcRXC7R3P6IQay7SfH1vjBejBD5nr6BvzWFygnTqHo4Fgw63xaDqCWV4ZzW89yxhzGAPjiP6g0Oo4RrNbptDr7ILPY4jDYOMBSOCoDRQ5QwobZSYAgFgDD6DLgzKIABeGRwZSYECkk2ACFuAFENPRLMBxOUqTSHHTgLd3PiIOyKZzJsLmFJuGLqf9jOcyBpgFAbryiKQxlBdrBpsI3HhjGRlRhVd1aAxmGwOFA0dQEjNdVQrVAANoPGqqDQO7hUVQVOBUAA0CyoZisrM91BDFgAXyw-YHclRbTrkp5RD4QOGqCyWIhKQGgyFLOGdGUIPGgontUlcGlIJmAMrAMrsKz5hP5QoWFglcMUyrlmpAhpNR1EmohDrhscV56Z3rAYBgTgAemXajgmDUvTg2k4AA4AAyH5dJ6v4ZcARioFzGA4rp9mOCnF0oVFnjrfC6Xq-Xm%203u8PY8H11S9rx6W8LiobZdggZ9HjfAY5y-Fc1w3W5-2sQCDxPKtHzwS9l2gkIwPeO8aiuG47gzUcX2od8vXnRcUN-dCd0wo9sOA5J8IvZcKNuRBQBIz4Fi%20cYAF1eAg18hxBEdrSoCdkDgmdEI-Rjv1Qv82P3DicOcZMxGEqBpL4KCkRRWCaITei6OQn80K3HSsMIizEA0fTEjw4yxJM8soIFFTXzwUkrO4AAmA8729ek1CZBhWXkqBwuink%20QFJKL2iqUpHDA8pLIOUQzwKIIAAOnXfQAApDTK2TGjKpSAEoyCAA)

---

**Demo**:

[image: Edit Typescript Object Assertions]

**Demo Code**:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export type Todo = {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
};

export default function App() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = React.useState({} as Todo);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTodo = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
        const data = await res.json();

        setTodo(data);
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.toString());
      }
    };

    fetchTodo();
  });

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Todo</h1>
      {error && <p className="error">{error}</p>}
      {Object.keys(todo).length > 0 ? (
        <div className="todo">
          <h1>Id: {todo.id}</h1>
          <h1>UserId: {todo.userId}</h1>
          <h1>Title: {todo.title}</h1>
          <h1>Completed: {todo.completed.toString()}</h1>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for putting here the Notifications type.
Just adding that in Notification List the prop is called like this data={notificationData as Notifications} and in the list component "{data._embedded?.notifications to not have issues with notifications list still being empty while fetching "